# Unable to pass value to php POST via javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to update the text from textbox to database using the onclick event and calling a javascript function.

This is the javascript code

```
function send_post() 
{

    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url ="send_post.php";
    var fn = document.getElementById("post").value;

    var vars = "post="+fn;
    hr.open("POST",url,true);

    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencode");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status ==200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;

        }
    }
    hr.send(vars);
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = fn;

}
```

This is the php file code

```
<?php include 'inc/connect.inc.php'; 

$post =@$_POST['post'];
if ($post != "") {
    $date_added = date("Y-m-d");
    $added_by = "test123";
    $user_posted_to = "test123";

    $sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO posts VALUES('','$post','$date_added','$added_by','$user_posted_to')";
    $query = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die (mysql_error());
}
else{
    echo "Write something to post.";

}

?>
```

But I get this error from the php :

Undefined index: post  on line 3

Comment: What does this line return: `var fn = document.getElementById("post").value;` Is it undefined?

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MIME type you are trying to use is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (with a `d` on the end).

PHP doesn't know how to parse data encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencode` (without the `d`) so it doesn't populate `$_POST` for your code.

Answer (score -1):

Javascript part:

```
<script>
function getXMLObject(){
 var xmlHttp = false;
 try {
  xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
 }
 catch (e) {
  try {
   xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
  }
  catch (e2) {
   xmlHttp = false
  }
 }
 if (!xmlHttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
  xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 return xmlHttp;
}

var xmlhttp = new getXMLObject();

function send_post() {
 if(xmlhttp) {
  var post = document.getElementById("post").value;
  xmlhttp.open("POST","send_post.php",true);
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = resultPost;
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xmlhttp.send("post=" + post);
 }
}

function resultPost() {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
  if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
   alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

PHP part:

```
<?php 

include 'inc/connect.inc.php'; 

if(isset($_POST['post']) && trim($_POST['post']) != '') $post = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['post']));
else $post = '';

if ($post != '') {
    $date_added = date("Y-m-d");
    $added_by = "test123";
    $user_posted_to = "test123";
    $sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO posts VALUES('','$post','$date_added','$added_by','$user_posted_to')";
    $query = mysql_query($sqlCommand);
    if(mysql_affected_rows($link) == 1){
     echo 'Operation successfully executed';
     exit;
    }
}
echo 'Write something to post.';

?>
```

Comment: This is just a massive wall of code with a recommendation to use a library (despite the [`javascript` tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) saying you shouldn't give library dependant answers on questions that aren't already using one). There's no explanation as to what is wrong with the code in the question, or why this code should fix it. It's also made changes to the PHP without saying what they are for (and it's left an SQL injection security hole in there).

Comment: This is still a massive wall of code with no explanation about what changes you've made or why.

Comment: I rewrote the entire javascript part to be Correct for PHP.
On the PHP side a escaped the POSTed variable and formatted the response for Javascript part.

Comment: "rewrote the entire javascript part to be Correct for PHP" - only *one letter* needed to be added to make it correct as far as PHP was concerned (well, assuming the user input was correct, but you changes didn't address the possibility that it wasn't). Also "rewrote the entire javascript part to be Correct for PHP" is really vague about what the changes are and says nothing about why the changes were needed. It doesn't even do the same thing with the data as the original code!

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations, I will try to do best next time.